# How to add two "add more" buttons in CCK form?

Tags: nodes, 6

I am using **cck 3.0** with **multi group fields**, basically multigroup provides one add more button for all fields inside multigroup fields.

I am trying to add two "add more" buttons in multigroup fields:

one button is for generic purpose and one for specific prupose.
For example:
I have 4 text fields in a compound form, and I have two button with names 1. "add more items" and 2. "add less fields".

If I click on "add more items repeat all fields", but if I click on "add more less fields button" repeat all field but display only first 3 fields and the forth one is by default display none. How can I do this?

I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: You have to use [ahah](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#ahah) for doing this. Also take a look [here](http://drupal.org/project/ahah_helper)

Comment: any thing else?